# enable binding doesn't work

Tags: html, css, knockout.js, data-binding

```
 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <button class="btn btn-danger pull-right btn-block" data-bind="enable: DeletedEnable">Delete</button>                            
 </div>
```

Even when the `DeletedEnable` is `false`, the enable property doesn't work, and the `button` is still enabled.

```
self.CurrentStatusIsDraft= ko.pureComputed(function () {
        return false;
    });

self.DeletedEnable = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        return self.CurrentStatusIsDraft() ;
    });
```

Comment: As you can see in this JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8cmLnyL5/ the code you are showing is working as you expect. if there is no error in your browser's console that might cause this issue then please show more details of your model.

Comment: @Matt.kaaj honestly i don't have any console errors.

Comment: Parisa, can you show more details then? Without more detail it's really hard to help.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3rnt2zsc/ this is how my view looks like and the model basically has the functions used in the view as i have in the question

Comment: Parisa jan look at the answer I just posted. Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example https://jsfiddle.net/3rnt2zsc/ :

A) it's not a good practice using `inline` `onClick`.
 Since you are using knockout simply use `click` event binding.

B) Try to put less `javascript logic` in your view.

C) Apply binding by using `new` instance of your model.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/of8qfdvL/1/

**View:**

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
   <div class="col-lg-offset-6 col-md-offset-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
         <button class="btn btn-default btn-gb-default btn-block pull-right" data-bind="enable: ContinuedEnabled, click:OnContinue">Continue</button>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-danger pull-right btn-block" data-bind="enable: DeletedEnabled(), click:OnDelete">Delete</button>
      <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(DeletedEnabled, null, 2)"></pre>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Model:**

```
var viewModel = function() {
   var self = this;
   self.SubmissionId = ko.observable(1234);
   self.LastPageId = ko.observable(2);
   self.ContinuedEnabled = ko.observable(true);  // you can set the value based on your logic

   self.OnContinue = function(){
      console.log("SubmissionId:",self.SubmissionId());
      console.log("LastPageId:",self.LastPageId());
   }

   self.OnDelete = function(){
      console.log("SubmissionId:",self.SubmissionId());
   }

   self.CurrentStatusIsDraft= ko.pureComputed(function () {
       return false;
   });

   self.DeletedEnabled = ko.pureComputed(function () {
      return self.CurrentStatusIsDraft() ;
   });
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel()); // apply a new instance of your model
```

Comment: i also found out that i am using jquery 3.1. However, it works fine in your fiddle because you are using older version of jquery. It also worked for me when i moved to older version of jquery.

Comment: @ParisaKordjamshidi it has nothing to do with `jquery 3.1`. In fact, it's a way you're binding your model. Look at my example using `jquery 3.1` https://jsfiddle.net/ahphsoq0/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qyeubea5/ this is how my js file is. How do i create a new instance?

Comment: @ParisaKordjamshidi You have a global object `gb` which I guess holds all your models in it. Inside each `pureComputed` functions let's  `console.log` the value of each observable dependencies and see if you are getting the same value that you expect.